# Disabling mail_safe during run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio

I am using ActionMailer to send SMS to users. I do this by writing my own `DeliveryMethod`. Inside my `DilveryMethod`, I implement the `deliver!` method and calls Twilio API to send SMS. Currently, in development, all e-mails are suppressed and, in staging, all e-mails are sent to one single e-mail address. This is problematic for SMS because it is not an e-mail; it will not be sent as an e-mail. I am wondering if there is a way to turn off mail_safe at runtime and let my `ActionMailer` do what it's supposed to do =)

Comment: How does /initializers/mail_safe.rb look like?